# Unbounded Memory Growth IOS App (CFString) - How to debug?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have an IOS app that displays images and text in a UITableView.  When I scroll up and down I get this unbounded memory growth.  I have used Allocations to attempt to find out where this memory growth comes from.  Please see below.  From what I can see, CFString takes up a huge amount of memory. It doesn't appear to be from my code(based on StackTrace of CFString) as seen in Figure 2.
Please can someone advise? I'm really stuck.  My app is crashing after a few minutes of scrolling after exceeding around 2GB of memory.  I would appreciate any general pointers on how to debug the origins of the memory issue.  The CFString stack trace appears all grayed out and I'm not sure how to proceed to diagnose the issue.

Figure 1
I am looking at CFString and the persistent memory is huge.

[image]

Figure 2
Clicking on CFString:

[image]

Comment: Advise you on what!?

Comment: How to reduce CFString memory persistent. its crashing my app

Comment: You are not showing a single line of code.  Nobody can tell what the problem is.

Comment: sorry i just thought the stack trace would be give me an idea of where to look.  And since it is all grayed out the CFString memory accumulation is not associated with my code.  My app is a huge project and was hoping the stack trace could narrow it down so that I could post a more clinical set of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Instruments app, in the Xcode utilities folder. Specifically you want the Leaks instrument. It will find leaked memory, and then help you figure out where that memory gets allocated.

Run your app for a while, then break it and examine your heap.
(It's rather complex and tricky to use. Much more than I can explain in an SO answer. I suggest digging up a WWDC video or other tutorial on using it.)

There is also a simple memory graph tool in Xcode that flags leaked blocks, but it doesn't give you as much information. (It's one of the little icons in the debug bar above the debug console. The icon is 3 little circles with lines between them.)